# Azure Application Gateway - Route / and /* to different backend pools

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to set up Azure Application Gateway for the first time and finally got parts of it running. My goal is to have some specific routes forwarded to a storage account and all other routes forwarded to a function app.

This is the routing that I want to achieve:

```
/ --> storage account
/favicon.ico --> storage account
... some more of those ...

/* --> function app
```

Having only the storage account routing configured, everything seems fine. But the moment I add the `/*` wildcard, also `/` is no longer routed to the storage account.

Here are some screenshots:

**This works**
[image: This works]

**This does not work**
[image: This does not work]

**This is not allowed**
[image: This is not allowed]

Is the routing I want to do even possible and if so, how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you try using **//** on path like [this](https://i.imgur.com/lzvzDiB.png)

Comment: Have you tried setting the Function App backend pool as the default backend pool?  Path-based routing does have a default backend settings and pool you can set for when no paths match your path map and I'd imagine that your non-working example would work if you removed the "/*" rule and set "api" as your default backend pool.

Comment: Thank @DusDee for the tip! I will definitely try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have created application gateway standard v2 sku with backend pool one for [storage account](https://charbelnemnom.com/how-to-configure-application-gateway-in-front-of-azure-blob-storage/) another one for function App like below:

[image]

To forward specific routes to storage account and all other routes forwarded to a function app, While creating application gateway add path `/favicon` and add backend target as storage backend pool like below:

[image]

To forward on function app add path `/Favicon/*` and add backend target as function backend pool like below:

[image]

In health probe both the path are added and forwarded to respective service successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

[image]